# How to send Ctrl+C to all iTerm2 tabs except the current in AppleScript?

Tags: applescript, iterm2

I have this code that sends a specific command to all tabs including the current one, in iTerm2. But, sometimes, some tabs are stuck and I want to get them to a shell prompt before trying to execute the command. However, sending Ctrl+C to the current tab, will stop the script from continuing.

I want to send the kill signal to all other tabs but not the current one.

```
osascript \
    -e 'tell application "iTerm"' \
    -e " tell current window" \
    -e '  repeat with aTab in tabs' \
    -e '   tell aTab' \
    -e '    repeat with asession in sessions' \
    -e '     tell asession' \
    -e '      tell application "System Events" to keystroke "c" using {control down}' \
    -e '     end tell' \
    -e '    end repeat' \
    -e '   end tell' \
    -e '  end repeat' \
    -e ' end tell' \
    -e 'end tell'
```

I tried conditioning "tell aTab" with "if aTab is not equal current tab", but that still didn't work.

Comment: Using `"System Events"` to `keystroke/keycode` is **UI Scripting** and it require that the target _window_ and _tab_ to have _focus_ when executing each `keystroke/keycode` _command_.

Comment: I see, do you have other recommendations on how to achieve what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following *example* **AppleScript** *code* was tested in **Script Editor** under **macOS Catalina** and **iTerm2**, Build 3.3.12, and worked for me without issues as is, with the current *window* having multiple *tabs* each with a single *session*, and except for the *tab* that was the *current tab* when executed, stopped the running *process* in each *tab*.

```applescript
tell application "iTerm"
    activate
    tell current window
        set excludeTab to current tab
        select tab 1
        repeat with aTab in tabs
            select aTab
            if current tab is not equal to excludeTab then
                tell current session
                    tell application "System Events" to ¬
                        key code 8 using {control down}
                end tell
            end if
        end repeat
        select excludeTab
    end tell
end tell
```

---

**Notes:**

Instead of using `osascript -e command` on a *script* such as this, I'd highly recommend creating an executable *file* with a `#!/usr/bin/osascript` *shebang* and then just copy and paste the *example* **AppleScript** *code* into the executable *file* as is. This IMO is much easier to maintain and modify as needed then using `osascript -e command` on a *script* such as this.

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and sans any included *error handling* does not contain any additional *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>